# How do I use fplot for a function with a variable and a parameter?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot a function that is in a separate .m file:

```
function V = Vitesse_Glissade(x, Courbe)
%some code
end
```

x is a variable evaluated between 0 and 25, but Courbe is a 4th order polinomial in the form of a vector that the function uses.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
figure
fplot(@(x) 'Vitesse_Glissade',[0 25], Courbe);
```

I get this error message:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in fplot (line 96)
maxstep = (xmax - xmin) / N;

Error in Glissage (line 37)
fplot(@(x) 'Vitesse_Glissade',[0 25], Courbe);
```

I have looked at posts where for multiple variable input in fplot, but since I use a vector as a parameter, it's different.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is not how function handles work. Use this syntax instead:

```
fplot(@(x)Vitesse_Glissade(x,Courbe),[0 25]);
```